# Problem with DateTimePicker control: Blank / Delete Date not possible

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I need for my data base GUI a date input control. The DateTimePicker looks good.
But I have a finished date field that must allow empty / blank date.
It must also be possible to clear a date to blank if a date was already entered.
I got a cumbersome solution that uses DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime as identifier for blank.
But when DateTimePicker.value = MinimumDateTime and I mouse click dropdown, the Calender is 1753.
But to set the Date to today in dropdown event doesn't help.

```
private void dtpDatum_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
        dtpDatum.Value = DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime;
}

private void dtpDatum_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtpDatum.Value > DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime)
        dtpDatum.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    else
        dtpDatum.CustomFormat = " ";
}

private void dtpDatum_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtpDatum.Value == DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime)
        dtpDatum.Value = DateTime.Today;
    dtpDatum.Refresh();
}
```

I wonder if there is a way / a better way get blank date handeled with GUI from data base separated?
I am also thinking of using textbox, but then I have to validate input and don't have a calender.

Be able to select a date from today on, when picker is blanked before.

Comment: Why not use `null` for empty? `dtpDatum.Value = null;`

Comment: @RandRandom The Value is non-nullable DateTime and the DateTimePicker doesn't support `null` values anyway

Comment: Did you also set `dtpDatum.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`? Doesn't change the min value, but the UI should be blank. Or, you could set it t, e.g., `.CustomFormat = "<NULL>"`

Comment: @Jimi - okay, didn't know - I am wpf dev - maybe switching to latest winforms version would be an option nullabilty seems to be merged already https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/6906 (edit: checked commit seems to be c# nullability feature, and not what I assumed from the title)

Comment: @RandRandom The Type of `Value` is still `DateTime`, not `DateTime?`. It would be a breaking change. You also have to deal with the underlying Win32 Control (what you do not have in WPF) -- I usually handle this either with a Custom Control or setting a Binding object that handles the `Format` and `Parse` events. You also have the option to send `DTS_SHOWNONE` to the Win32 Control (or set `ShowCheckBox = true`), so it shows a checkbox, used to determine whether the DateTime value is valid or not

Comment: @Rand Random
I use Win Forms and it isn't possible: "Null can not be converted to DateTime..."@Jimi

Comment: Rand Random
I use Win Forms and it isn't possible: "Null can not be converted to DateTime..."
@Jimi
Of course, I did set it to custom.
>> or set ShowCheckBox = true
Thank you very much. That possibility I have overlooked.
The problem here is, that when unchecked, the value is still the date and not null.
So how can I handle the two-way bindig to a class property properly?

Comment: Not sure if possible on WinForms maybe @Jimi will know, bit I would do a multivaluebinding - so your property is bound to both the IsChecked of the Checkbox and the DateTime - with your property being a Nullable DateTime the multivaluebinding would take it and turn it into a regular datetime and ischecked false on null